# Bash skip sleep and go to next loop iteration

Tags: bash, loops, sleep

I have a bash loop that looks like this:

```
something(){
    echo "something"
}

while true; do
    something
    sleep 10s
done | otherCommand
```

When the loop is in the sleep state, I want to be able to be able to run a function from the terminal that will skip the sleep step and go on to the next iteration of the loop.

For example, if the script has been sleeping for 5 seconds, I want the command to stop the script from sleeping, go on to the next iteration of the loop, run `something`, and continue sleeping again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not foolproof, but may be robust enough:

To interrupt the `sleep` command, run:

```
pkill -f 'sleep 10s'
```

<sup>Note that the script running the `sleep` command prints something like the following to stderr when `sleep` is killed: `<script-path>: line <line-number>: <pid> Terminated: 15          sleep 10s`. Curiously, you cannot suppress this script with `sleep 10s 2>/dev/null`; to suppress it, you have to either apply `2>/dev/null` to the `while` loop as a whole, or to the script invocation as a whole.</sup>

As @miken32 points out in the comments, this command tries to kill *all* commands whose invocation command line matches `sleep 10s`, though - unless you're running as `root` - killing will only succeed for matches among *your* processed due to lack of permission to kill *other* users' processes.

To be safe*r*, you can explicitly restrict matches to your own processes:

```
pkill -u "$(id -u)" -f 'sleep 10s'
```

Truly safe use, however, requires that you capture your running script's PID (process ID), save it to a file, and use the PID from that file with `pkill`'s `-P` option, which limits matches to child processes of the specified PID - see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/575708/225111) (thanks, @miken32).

Comment: Last time I tried this it didn't seem to work for loops. I don't know why. It works now, thanks.

Comment: Worth mentioning this will kill any of those `sleep` commands whether they were started from the script or not. Probably not worth worrying about, but [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575704/how-can-i-wake-a-sleeping-bash-script) has a detailed solution for the case where the command you're looking to kill isn't unique.

Comment: @miken32 Yeah I was trying to do something with the PID. For some reason it doesn't seem to work when sleep is in a loop. Maybe I'm just a noob.

Comment: @Marcel - in your other post you didn't tell `pkill` which child process to kill. If you tried `pkill -P $PARENTPID -f sleep` it should work. Substitute `$PARENTPID` with the pid of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the sleep, use something like a file you can touch:

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/skipsleep ]; then
   sleep 10
fi
```

When you want to interrupt the sleep command, kill it!

Comment: I want it to skip the current sleep. Say it has been sleeping for 5s. I want the command to stop the script from sleeping, go to the next iteration of the loop, run `something` and start sleeping again. If I am reading that file correctly, it does not do that but rather always skips the sleep if the file `/tmp/skipsleep`. Sorry if my question was vague.

Answer (score 0):

You could read from a named pipe with `read -t 10` instead of sleeping: props for named pipe added by "that other guy"

```
something()
{
  echo "something"
}
somethingelse()
{
  echo "something else"
}

mkfifo ~/.myfifo
while cat ~/.myfifo; do true; done |
  while true
  do
    something
    read -t 10 && somethingelse
  done
```

Now whenever another script writes to the fifo with `echo > ~/.myfifo`, the loop will skip its current wait and continue to the next iteration.

This way, different users or different scripts waiting ten seconds will not interfere with each other.

Solution below works if script is running in foreground and you are waiting. Of course you would need a valid loop exit condition. You can also check the value entered and act on it differently. In this case pressing any key except 'j' will iterate the loop. Pressing 'j' will pipe the output of somethingelse to awk.

```
 something()
 {
    echo "something"
 }
 somethingelse()
 {
    echo "something else"
 }

 while true; do
     something |awk '{print "piping something: " $0 }'
     read -t 3 -s -n 1 answer

     if [ $? == 0 ]; then 
        echo "you didn't want to wait!"
     fi

     if [ "$answer" = "j" ]; then
        somethingelse | awk '{print "piping something else: " $0 }'
     fi
 done
```

Comment: I fail to see how this would help me. Please elaborate.

Comment: no but he asked how he could interrupt the sleep and iterate the loop.

Comment: the loop is supposed to echo a string and pipe it into somethingelse, not call it.

Answer (score 0):

If its interactive then just use "read -t #" instead of "sleep #".

You can then just press enter to skip the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old, but a very simple, elegant solution is to iterate a non existant, empty or 0 set variable, while checking if it has some value first. In this case the ternary operator works as intended

```bash
for((;;)){
  # skip an interation
  (( i ))&& do something || i=1
  
  # skip 5 iterations
  (( n >= 5 ))&& do something ||
    ((n++))
}
```